# Accessing environment variables via webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

I have developed a `react webpack` application and I have implemented as follows to access `environment variables`.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
       filename: 'bundle.js',
   },

   devServer: {
       inline: true,
       disableHostCheck: true,
       host: '0.0.0.0',
       port: 8080
   },

   module: {
       loaders: [
           {
               test: /\.jsx?$/,
               exclude: /node_modules/,
               loader: 'babel-loader',

               query: {
                   presets: ['es2015', 'react']
               }
           }
       ]
   },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        ENV_VAR: JSON.stringify(process.env.ENV_VAR)
      }
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

and in my **config.js** I have implemented as follows to maintain my config structure.

```
export default () => {
  return {
    "configFromEnvVar": {
      "url": process.env.ENV_VAR || "http://url:8080"
    }
  }
};
```

I want to know if there is a better way to do this without having to use `process.env` in multiple locations. Any documentation or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks alot